# Statistically determining the median of a data set via quantiles of a sample

Tags: sample-size, algorithms, median

I was thinking of algorithms for statistically determining the median of a large data set. To estimate the complexity of my idea I need the following Probability:

- I have a dataset $\left\{x_i \right\}$ of size $n$ with unknown distribution
- I take a random sample $\left\{y_i \right\}\subset \left\{x_i \right\}$ of size $s\ll n$
- I determine the $\left(50+\varepsilon\right)$th and the $\left(50-\varepsilon\right)$th quantile $y^{0.5\pm \frac{\varepsilon}{100}}$

What is the probability of the median $x^{0.5}$ of the first data set $\left\{x_i \right\}$ being in the interval $\left[y^{0.5- \frac{\varepsilon}{100}},y^{0.5 + \frac{\varepsilon}{100}} \right]$ as a function of $n,s,\varepsilon$?

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: Given your objective, you will likely be interested in [The P2 algorithm](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/7959) and in [behavior of quantiles generally](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/45124).  The latter provides both direct and asymptotic answers.

Comment: @whuber thanks for the comment. I am not working on a project on this but want to test an algorithm theoretically. There are two problems with what you suggest:
1. I am looking for a precise answer not an approximation (military loss function), so the P2 algorithm does not work
2. I want to draw one sample and get the probability in dependence of the size of this sample -> central limit theorem does not work

Comment: I don't follow, because your questions asks for the probability that an interval will cover a median--on the face of it, that contemplates an "imprecise" answer.

Comment: consider a loss function where you get 1 if you hit the target exactly and 0 if you do not. i.e. i have to choose from the list of values rather than approximate. There is a chance I do not find it, but if I do it is the correct one

Comment: That sounds like a very different question than the one you posted.  Could you explain how they might be the same?