# Incremental updates for percentile estimates

Tags: simulation, monte-carlo, density-estimation

I want to estimate percentile statistics for time-series pairs $(t, y)$ over varying granularities of time (hour, day, month, etc)

For example, if I have the following pairs `(10:59, 3)`, `(11:01, 2)`, `(11:32, 5)`, the first point is part of a different *hour window*, but all three are part of the same *day window*.

When a new point arrives, I am recomputing the *hour window* statistics directly, by iterating over all data points in the window. Unfortunately, this does not scale to the longer time windows.

Is there a way to incrementally update the statistics for the longer time windows?

Comment: Welcome to CV.  We might already have an answer: could you explain how your problem differs, if at all, from the one discussed at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/7959?

Comment: Thanks! I think that answers it.